# In VMWare Workstation 8, can I print from DOS guest to Windows 7 host's XPS Writer or similar soft printer?

Tags: printing, vmware-workstation, print-to-pdf, disk-operating-system

VMWare insists on connecting virtual printer in guest to the **serial** port and naturally nothing works.
Windows allows assigning legacy LPT1 port but it exposed only to DOS on the host and VMWare complains about missing physical port.

Answer (score 0):

No, not to the **hosts** XPS printer, but you can print to a XPS or DPF printer **on the guest**.